# How to use Facebook API to get my OWN timeline/posts data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a site for a ONG that news section is a Facebook timeline post of your OWM profile.

The social_page plug-in is not good and not responsive, maximum width of 500px and does not have a adaptive design.

So I think I can use the Facebook's API to get information about fields ("message", "picture") from Facebook profile.

I do this in client with javascript, and I will read data and make simple HTML (photo and message) for the news.

the code for that is:

```
FB.api(
              '/user_id/posts',
              'GET',
              { "fields": "message,picture", "access_token": "access_token" },
              function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
              }
            );
```

But how i can do a Facebook token that grant access for this information with no expiration data?

The problem here is: Facebook will expire the access token, and I don't find a way to grant permission only to read posts with no expiration in client code.

Someone has a solution or knowledge if its possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Tanks for edit Jared Forth.

Comment: If you want to do this client-side, then you will have to make users login to your app first, so that you can use their own user token. Exposing any other kind of token in client-side code is just a no-go. Assuming that by "own profile" you are actually talking about a page, and not a user profile (otherwise you could not have used the page plugin to begin with) - get an extended page token, and store it to make the requests necessary from the server side. Not on every page load of course, but in a reasonable interval, and cached on your end.

Comment: I don't wanna users login to see the news... the news came from ONG's profile. I guess i can make a application token in debug mode forever, and get the ong's profile from server side and store in a session... 
I studying a way to make this application token in debug mode with no expiration, because the app is not for users use, but only to get information from profile. Facebook is very limited in this way... 
Their page-profile is ridiculous... a company of billions of dollars can't make a responsive plug-in... ?